# What's the best way to measure SEO on my Linkedin page?

Tags: html, seo, linkedin-api

I've spent quite a bit of time doing SEO on my LinkedIn page and wondered if there was a way I could measure and track how successful it's been.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Webmaster Pro.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at setting up a Google analytics account if you don't already have one and then run reports against your profile URL link for your linkedIn profile. You should check out this blog on Google Analytics for LinkedIn accounts.

http://keithpaul.net/2014/04/measuring-linkedin-google-analytics/#.VU8LKvlViko

Another way would be if you have a blog you can link to your LinkedIn account if you're a subject matter expert. Backlinking done right can help your exposure and rankings.